# Junit Test plug-in is failing with the following error with maven build even though Easymock, Cglib, Objenesis are also defined in the dependencies

Tags: java, maven, junit4

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(ClassExtensionHelper.java:57)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2068)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:1970)
    at com.infineon.stt.connection.service.test.ConnectionServiceTest.testNullPorts(ConnectionServiceTest.java:911)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)

Comment: Does not look like. Apart from that without a pom file and the appropriate test and how you called maven it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I have run the below command:  mvn clean verify -X > log

Comment: <dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>kxml</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>swtchart</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: Plug in pom: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
   <groupId>a.b.c.d</groupId>
   <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>a.b.c.d.MyApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Eclipse Plug-in Name </artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>

Comment: My test plug-in pom:
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
   <groupId>a.b.c.d</groupId>
   <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>a.b.c.d.MyApptest</groupId>
  <artifactId>Eclipse test Plug-in Name </artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
</project>

Comment: I have insatlled these required jars also like below: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=easymock/Eclipse_Plugin_Jar/org.easymock_3.0.0.jar -DgroupId=org -DartifactId=easyMock -Dversion=3.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=objenesis/Eclipse_Plugin_Jar/org.Objenesis_1.2.0.jar -DgroupId=org -DartifactId=Objenesis -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=cglib/Eclipse_Plugin_Jar/org.Cglib_2.2.0.jar -DgroupId=org -DartifactId=Cglib -Dversion=2.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar